# Apache Spark Scala CosmosDB Connector Writing DataFrame Back To Database

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb

I am playing around with Apache Spark with the Azure CosmosDB connectors in Scala and was wondering if anyone had examples or insight on how I would write my DataFrame back to a collection in my CosmosDB. Currently I am able to connect to my one collection and return the data and manipulate it but I want to write the results back to a different collection inside the same database.

I created a writeConfig that contains my EndPoint, MasterKey, Database, and the Collection that I want to write to.

I then tried writing it to the collection using the following line.

```
manipulatedData.toJSON.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).cosmosDB(writeConfig)
```

This runs fine and does not display any errors but nothing is showing up in my collection.

I went through the documentation I could find at https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark but did not have much luck with finding any examples of writing data back to the database.

If there is an easier way to write to a documentDB/cosmosDB than what I am doing? I am open to any options.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save to Cosmos DB directly from a Spark DataFrame just like you had noted.  You may not need to use `toJSON`, for example:

```
// Import SaveMode so you can Overwrite, Append, ErrorIfExists, Ignore
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}

// Create new DataFrame `df` which has slightly flights information 
// i.e. change the delay value to -999
val df = spark.sql("select -999 as delay, distance, origin, date, destination from c limit 5")

// Save to Cosmos DB (using Append in this case)
//    Ensure the baseConfig contains a Read-Write Key
//    The key provided in our examples is a Read-Only Key
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).cosmosDB(baseConfig)
```

As for the documentation, you are correct in that the save function should be have been better called out.  I've created [Include in User Guide / sample scripts how to save to Cosmos DB #91](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/issues/91) to address this.

As for the saving but seeing no error, by any chance is your config using the Read-Only key instead of the Read-write key?  I just created [Saving to CosmosDB using read-only key has no error #92](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/issues/92) calling out the same issue.